Microsoft Graph Powershell ErrorAction is not recognized in cmdlet
I'm in learning mode and understand that powershell has terminating and non-terminating errors. I am attempting to use a try / catch block for my script and believe it's a non-terminating error and would like to setup a txt log file for successes and errors however cannot figure out why -ErrorAction comes out with the following error -- The term '-ErrorAction' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks
##Import the Microsoft Graph Users module
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Users, Microsoft.Graph.Users.Actions

##Connect to Microsoft Graph with the user read/write permission
Connect-MgGraph -scope User.ReadWrite.All -NoWelcome

##Import csv user list
$users = Import-CSV "C:\temp\O365_FieldOps_Import.csv"

##Define the password profile settings within a hash table
$PasswordProfile = @{
    Password = "Password!"
    ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = $true
    ForceChangePasswordNextSignInWithMfa = $true
}

##Loop through and create each user
ForEach ($user in $users){
    
    try {
        #Create a new user object
        $newUser = New-MgUser -DisplayName $user.display_name `
        -PasswordProfile $PasswordProfile `
        -AccountEnabled `
        -MailNickName $user.mailnickname `
        -UserPrincipalName $user.userprincipalname `
        -Department $user.department `
        -JobTitle $user.job_title `
        -UsageLocation $user.UsageLocation `

        -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
        <#Do this if a terminating exception happens#>
        Write-Error $_
        Write-Host 'This is in catch'
    }

    # Assign licenses to the new user
    # Write-host "Assigning license: $($license.SkuPartNumber) to $($user.DisplayName)"
    #Set-MgUserLicense -UserId $newUser.Id -AddLicenses @{ SkuId = $user.SkuId } -RemoveLicenses @()
}


Remove the empty line preceding -ErrorAction Stop

Thank Marthias-- that was the answer.
